# Best way to integrate items from multiple sources?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, architecture, client-server

I have been tasked with integrating nodes from two different systems.  For demonstration purposes, suppose I have to display Google Drive and OneDrive nodes in the same tree view together allowing interoperability like dragging from one system to the other among other things.  The system is a web-client - server architecture, and there are currently more than 4+ client applications utilizing the same server application.  Most of the issues are solved by having a property on our node object indicating the System source.  (OneDrive, GoogleDrive) However, the requests that involve just the ID are not serviceable without knowing the system the ID comes from.  We are a small team, so while the purity of solution is preferred, the amount of work to achieve a solution is also a factor. Several of the solutions evaluated have been:

1. NodeSource in ID. (i.e. GD-342341234lkj4, OD-2r23rkjmjfsdlf)
2. Separate WebApi Controllers for each external node type. (Doesn't seem scalable for adding more Node Sources i.e. iCloud)
3. One set of WebApi controllers that deal with all External node types. (Would allow for more Node Sources in the future, but not much cleaner than the NodeSource in the ID)

Currently, the ID solution has been the solution of choice due to the lower amount of work involved not only for the Server side code, but it would also reduce the amount of work needed by the client applications to utilize the new functionality.  We currently are utilizing a three-tier architecture on our server side, and with the ID solution, looking at adding a fourth that acts as a routing layer:

Web Controllers -> Business Logic -> Data Access

to

Web Controllers -> Routing on ID --> OneDrive Business Logic -> OneDrive API

```
                             \
                              -> Google Drive Business Logic -> GoogleDrive API
```

If anyone has any other ideas on how to implement this, or reasons why not, I would love to hear it!  Or if you feel that this question doesn't belong here, please point me to the area where I should ask it.